# arabic text printing using raw printing in c#

Tags: vb.net

I need to print arabic text using raw printing am using below code. But its printing ????? instated of text

```
    Public Function SendStringToPrinter(szPrinterName As String, szString As String) As Boolean
    If PrinterOpen Then
        Dim pBytes As IntPtr
        Dim dwCount As Int32
        Dim dwWritten As Int32 = 0

        dwCount = szString.Length

        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString)

        SendStringToPrinter = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, dwWritten)

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes)
    Else
        SendStringToPrinter = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please do not add tags that are irrelevant for the question.

Comment: well its an encoding problem, and obviously your enconding is ASCII instead of UTF8, as in your code I don't know where the string comes, its hard to say where to set the encoding.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani can you please send a sample code

Comment: where that text comes from? reading from a file? for example if so you must read with System.Text.Encoding.UTF8. ideal with persian that is exactly the same, if you tell me where it comes from i can help better, i haven't worked with vb for more than 10 years so i should check syntax in my pc before answering

Comment: You can do something like this: `Dim CurrentEncoding As Encoding = If((CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft), Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage), Encoding.Unicode)`  `Dim TextBytes As Byte() = CurrentEncoding.GetBytes("[Your Text]")`. But, as already noted, much depends on the original encoding and if it's different from the Local CodePage. Thus, `Encoding.Unicode` might not be the right fallback encoding.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Bro. The string variable have text including Arabic i.e., `szString` and that string is coming from database. Can u please help Us.

Comment: If you don't know what encoding was used when the strings were stored, check the `COLLATIONPROPERTY` of that field, and see what `CodePage` or `LCID` was used. You can then initialize a new `Encoding` with `Dim StringEncoding As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding([CodePage])`

Comment: @Venkannat how did you solve this?